# VB/C# - ComboBox changing value when click on dropdown - bug

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and its working well.

Also i had binds two events on it.

one to detect selection change and another to drop down on one click

Given is to detect selection change:

```
  Private Sub DataGridView2Rachunek_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2Rachunek.EditingControlShowing
        ' Only for a DatagridComboBoxColumn at ColumnIndex 1.
        If DataGridView2Rachunek.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = DataGridView2Rachunek.Columns("Stan").Index Then
            Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
            If (combo IsNot Nothing) Then
                ' Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid 
                ' adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.
                RemoveHandler combo.SelectionChangeCommitted, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted)

                ' Add the event handler. 
                AddHandler combo.SelectionChangeCommitted, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
        Console.WriteLine("Row: {0}, Value: {1}, id: {2}", DataGridView2Rachunek.CurrentCell.RowIndex, combo.SelectedItem)

End Sub
```

and this is to dropdown on click of first one:

```
Private Sub DataGridViewRachunek_rowselected(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2Rachunek.CellClick


    If e.RowIndex < 0 Then
        Exit Sub



    Else
            DataGridView2Rachunek.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = True


        If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView2Rachunek.Columns("Stan").Index Then
            DataGridView2Rachunek.BeginEdit(True)

            DirectCast(DataGridView2Rachunek.EditingControl, ComboBox).DroppedDown = True
        End If


    End If

End Sub
```

Everything is working excellent but there is small bug.

Example: I have multiple rows. How to prevent bug ?:

- select an option in (example) 2nd row and comboboxcolumn,
- click on (for example) 1st row and comboboxcolumn then happen this: **comboBox get value of 2nd row for around 0.2sec, next it go back to value which was before click.**

If I delete event to detect selection change bug don't happen.

Overall its not causing any bugs, it is only visual.. Do you guys have an idea what can I do with this?

Comment: You are simply seeing that DGV uses the *same* combobox control to edit any cell in the grid.  That makes it efficient, keeping the number of controls to a minimum is quite important.  Why it takes noticeable time to get its value updated probably has something to do with the amount of data in the grid.  You should not use the combobox events to see changes to the cell, DGV has its own events for that.

Comment: Thanks Hans. yes, i know that, before I try to use an `cellValueChanged` But It triggers to often. I mean, when data is downloaded from database and filling to DGV. It's why I was looking for another way to get that event and I found used way on few web pages. I need to trigger event exacly when user click on item in DropDownList

Comment: Well, just don't subscribe the event until after you filled it, easy peasy.

Comment: You have right. But what if I reload data in DGV?

Comment: It is in your snippet, if it had teeth then it would have bit you :)  The RemoveHandler statement works for the CellValueChanged event as well.

Comment: Ok so i try many ways.... and finally i found that problem is with BeginEdit function... This function cause that problem. I changed this to EditOnEnter and still problem happens, but value faster disappear. Idk how to solve this...